# how do I process images item AND common item in the same pipeline.py for scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

now I have defined four items in items.py,such as:

```
#item.py
class schoolItem(scrapy.Item):
class specialtyItem(scrapy.Item):
class raidersItem(scrapy.Item):
class picturesItem(scrapy.Item):
```

and then,I will yield four item in the one same spider.py.
I will process four items in the pipeline.py.But three items are data item from webpage_parse,the a other item is a imageItem.so I decide to call imagesPipeline class to process images item.
my thoughts are  such as :

```
#pipeline.py
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
.....
.....
  def process_item(self,item,spider):
    if isinstance(item,schoolItem):
        self.db[self.coll_a].insert(dict(item))  
    elif isinstance(item,specialtyItem):
        self.db[self.coll_b].insert(dict(item))
    elif isinstance(item,raidersItem):
        self.db[self.coll_c].insert(dict(item))
    elif isinstance(item,picturesItem):
        self.get_media_requests(item, info)
    return item

  def get_media_requests(self, item, info):        
        for url in item["image_urls"]:
            yield scrapy.Request(url,meta={'cname': item["cname"]})
```

But I dont konw if the scrapy will recogonize the imageItem?
I want process the imageItem with other three item in the same time ,what should I do?